Getting today's hebrew calender date
I'm using babel for hebrew fonts because I have various package-issues with polyglossia. I was wondering if there is a way to get today's date, by the Jewish calender?
This should be similar to how I'd type \today and get October 30th 2024.
The only relevent package I could come across was cjhebrew, but it'd require me to manually type today's date.

Sadly, there is  a bug in the file babel-ca-hebrew.tex (the calendar converter), but it’s easily fixable. Just replace in line 201 #3=\ifcase #1\relax by #3=\ifcase #1 (in other words, remove the \relax). (I’ll release a new version in a week or so with some bug fixes, including this one.) With this change, the following MWE works (luatex):
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[hebrew, provide={calendar=hebrew},bidi=basic]{babel}

\babelfont{rm}{NewComputerModern10}

\begin{document}

\today

\end{document}



Thanks! this actually works for me after removing 'bidi=basic' and the font. But it seems to have issues when I'm trying to have both english and hebrew in the same document? That is, I'd like to have both regular date and hebrew-date, and this allows only the hebrew date?

You have to load english too, and then switch the language. For example: \foreignlanguage[date]{english}{\today}. For a more precise explanation about this, it’s necessary a more precise explanation of the structure of your document. From yor comment, it seems you are using pdftex. It’s strongly advisable to use luatex instead, because pdftex presents severe limitations in ‘complex’ scripts.
